# how to identify digital chars as date from a string column in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I would like to extract digital chars from a string in a column of spark dataframe.

e.g.

```
   id    val (string)
   58    [dttg] 201805_mogtca_onvt
   91    20050221_frcas
   17    201709 dcsevas
```

I need:

```
 id     a_date      year     month     
 58     201805      2018     05
 91     20050221    2005     02
 17     201709      2017     09
```

I am trying:

```
 df.withColumn('date', DF.to_date(F.col('val').isdigit() # how to get digital chars ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by removing all non numeric characters through a regex_replace for instance:

```
df.withColumn("a_date", regexp_replace($"val", "[^0-9]", ""))
```

Then, since you seem to have different time format in each row, the easiest way is by using substrings

```
df.withColumn("a_date", regexp_replace($"val", "[^0-9]", ""))
  .withColumn("year", substring($"a_date", 0, 4)) 
  .withColumn("month", substring($"a_date", 5, 2))
  .drop("val")
```

**INPUT**

```
+---+-------------------------+
|id |val                      |
+---+-------------------------+
|58 |[dttg] 201805_mogtca_onvt|
|91 |20050221_frcas           |
|17 |201709 dcsevas           |
+---+-------------------------+
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+---+--------+----+-----+
|id |a_date  |year|month|
+---+--------+----+-----+
|58 |201805  |2018|05   |
|91 |20050221|2005|02   |
|17 |201709  |2017|09   |
+---+--------+----+-----+
```